# rails json query for pagination on habtm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have 2 models : `Document` and `Place`, which are habtm in relation to each other.

In a search form, I want to implement an autocomplete function that proposes the places that are related to documents (i.e. not all places in the `places` table).

This is my code :

```
def enum_places
    @locus = Place.joins(:documents).map{ |f| f.place }.where("place like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
    render json @locus.map(&:place)
end
```

This is what the server log shows:

```
Processing by DocumentsController#show as JSON
Parameters: {"term"=>"Dou", "id"=>"enumplaces"}
Acte Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE "documents"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

And then of course the error is :

```
RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Document with 'id'=enumplace):
```

It turns out that the url that the autocomplete is looking for is

```
http://localhost:3000/documents/enumplace?term=Dou
```

This is in my routes.rb :

```
get 'documents/enumplace' => 'documents#enum_place'
```

and when I do rails routes this line seems correct :

```
documenets_enumplaces GET    /documents/enumplaces(.:format) documents#enum_places
```

BUT.... the method in documents_controller.rb that is called is... show !

Thanks !

Comment: Looks like you are routing to /documents/enumplaces

Comment: Did you setup route for autocomplete ? I think you need to post more code

Comment: That's correct, I updated the question.

Comment: are you using autocomplete-rails?

Comment: yes I am and it works good on other fields. It seems to be a routing problem

Answer (score 0):

try this in routes:

```
resources :documents do 
  get :autocomplete_document_place, :on => :collection
end
```

and

```
DocumentsController
autocomplete :document, :place
```

Comment: then I get `undefined method 'autocomplete' for DocumentController:Class` - my fault. I'm NOT using autocomplete-rails as all my other autocomplete fields function well without this.

Answer (score 0):

Got it !

1. I needed to add a proper route for "show".
2. The code for the search of places is

   def enum_document_place
        @locus = Place.joins(:documents).where("place like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
        render json: @locus.map(&:place)
    end